Remove a specific subnode when one of its tags include a specific value
I'm trying to read a xml file, search its content for any tag which has a specific value and then remove the whole subnode which includes that tag.
Let's say the xml file looks like this:
<project name="test">
  <paramlist name="Settings">
    <param name="User1" id="0001" />
    <param name="USer2" id="0002" />
  </paramlist>
  <definitions>
    <Definition>
      <schematic>
        <User name="User3">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0003" />
            <param name="Group" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        <User name="account3">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0003" />
            <param name="style" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        <User name="User4">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0004" />
            <param name="Group" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        <User name="account4">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0004" />
            <param name="style" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>     
      </schematic>   
    </Definition>
  </definitions>
</project>

I'm trying to find a way to all "User" subnodes where value is "0004".
I got inspiration from Remove a specific xml tag with ElementTree in python and tried the following but didn't really worked as I expected:
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

    target_node = 'schematic'
    target_node_first_parent = 'User'
    target_node_second_parent = 'paramlist'
    target_node = 'param'
    target_text = 'value=\"0004\"'

    for nodes in root.iter(target_node):
        for first_nodes in nodes.iter(target_node_first_parent):
            for second_node in first_nodes.iter(target_node_second_parent):
                for subnode in second_node.iter(target_node):
                    if target_text in subnode.text:
                        nodes.remove(first_nodes)

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write('output.xml')


It is so much easier to implement via XSLT. And just call that XSLT from Python.

Did any of the answers resolve your issue?

Here is an XSLT based solution.
It is using a so called Identity Transform pattern.
One single XSLT template does the job:
<xsl:template match="User[paramlist/param[@value='0004']]" />

Input XML
<project name="test">
    <paramlist name="Settings">
        <param name="User1" id="0001"/>
        <param name="USer2" id="0002"/>
    </paramlist>
    <definitions>
        <Definition>
            <schematic>
                <User name="User3">
                    <paramlist name="">
                        <param name="id" value="0003"/>
                        <param name="Group" value=""/>
                    </paramlist>
                </User>
                <User name="account3">
                    <paramlist name="">
                        <param name="id" value="0003"/>
                        <param name="style" value=""/>
                    </paramlist>
                </User>
                <User name="User4">
                    <paramlist name="">
                        <param name="id" value="0004"/>
                        <param name="Group" value=""/>
                    </paramlist>
                </User>
                <User name="account4">
                    <paramlist name="">
                        <param name="id" value="0004"/>
                        <param name="style" value=""/>
                    </paramlist>
                </User>
            </schematic>
        </Definition>
    </definitions>
</project>

XSLT 1.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="User[paramlist/param[@value='0004']]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<project name="test">
  <paramlist name="Settings">
    <param name="User1" id="0001"/>
    <param name="USer2" id="0002"/>
  </paramlist>
  <definitions>
    <Definition>
      <schematic>
        <User name="User3">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0003"/>
            <param name="Group" value=""/>
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        <User name="account3">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0003"/>
            <param name="style" value=""/>
          </paramlist>
        </User>
      </schematic>
    </Definition>
  </definitions>
</project>

Python
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("Input.xml")
style = lx.parse("Process.xslt")
outfile = "Output.xml"

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open(outfile, "wb") as f:
    f.write(result)


The easiest way would be to use xpath() and getparent() in lxml...
from lxml import etree

# Not including the entire XML to keep it simple.
xml_string = """<project name="test">...</project>"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

for user_elem in root.xpath(f".//User[.//param[@name='id'][@value='0004']]"):
    user_elem.getparent().remove(user_elem)

etree.dump(root)  # Dump the tree to the console for testing. You can also write to a file at this point.

If you have to stick with ElementTree you can do something similar, you just need to find the schematic parent and check for the param separately...
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Not including the entire XML to keep it simple.
xml_string = """<project name="test">...</project>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

for schematic_elem in root.findall(".//schematic"):
    for user_elem in schematic_elem.findall(f".//User"):
        target_param = user_elem.findall(".//param[@name='id'][@value='0004']")
        if len(target_param) > 0:
            schematic_elem.remove(user_elem)

ET.dump(root)  # Dump the tree to the console. You can also write to a file at this point.


You have to search e.g. with XPath capabilities child/.. the parent tag to remove a child tag parent.remove(child):
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_ ="""<project name="test">
  <paramlist name="Settings">
    <param name="User1" id="0001" />
    <param name="USer2" id="0002" />
  </paramlist>
  <definitions>
    <Definition>
      <schematic>
        <User name="User3">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0003" />
            <param name="Group" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        <User name="account3">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0003" />
            <param name="style" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        <User name="User4">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0004" />
            <param name="Group" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        <User name="account4">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0004" />
            <param name="style" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>     
      </schematic>   
    </Definition>
  </definitions>
</project>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_)

# remove the whole user area
for user in root.findall(".//User"):
    pattern = user.find(".//param[@value='0004']")
    if pattern is not None:
        root.find(".//User/..").remove(user)

ET.dump(root)

Output:
<project name="test">
  <paramlist name="Settings">
    <param name="User1" id="0001" />
    <param name="USer2" id="0002" />
  </paramlist>
  <definitions>
    <Definition>
      <schematic>
        <User name="User3">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0003" />
            <param name="Group" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        <User name="account3">
          <paramlist name="">
            <param name="id" value="0003" />
            <param name="style" value="" />
          </paramlist>
        </User>
        </schematic>   
    </Definition>
  </definitions>
</project>


Unless I'm reading the question wrong, they want to delete the entire User element; not just the param.

Thanks @Daniel Haley than I misunderstood the question. I added another part for this.
